# Location of temporary executables during install4j installation

Tags: install4j

During the installation executables are generated in the temp directory (e.g. `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j2120.tmp_dir1543476478`). Where the last part seems to be mostly random.

Is there a way to configure this location? We have a client with restrictions on executables in the temp-directory, in order for them to add an exception they need to know in advance where the files will be. So for example if we could set it to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\<our application name>` that should solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows there is a command line option for the installer to set the temporary directory:

```
installer.exe -temp <path to temp dir>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that only changes where the log-file is created. All other files still end up in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j2120.tmp_dir1543476478`. Could I change exe4j.tempDir perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot there actually was an option to set the temp directory, I've changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: That works for the install! Is there a way to set that option when running updates as well? I tried setting it in the updaterArguments of `UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate` but that didn't work.

Comment: You would have to locate the action named "Set installer arguments" in the updater application and add the `-temp` argument there.

Comment: I don't have an updater app (that executes the installer). I use `UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate`. I've tried passing `-temp` in the `arguments` parameter. I've also tried setting it in the "installer arguments" property on the "Schedule update installation" to no avail.

Comment: Do you use the new method with the signature `executeScheduledUpdate(List<String> updaterArguments, boolean restartLauncher, List<String> launcherArguments, Runnable shutdownRunnable)`? In that case, you should pass a list with the two arguments `-temp` and the directory path to the `updaterArguments` parameter.

Comment: This is on version 7.0.8 so there is only one list of arguments (the `updaterArguments`). `UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate(Arrays.asList("-temp", "c:\tmp", "-q", "-splash", "Uppdaterar..."), true,
    null);`

Comment: OK, but that passes the arguments to the new installer. Does `c:\tmp˚ exist and is it writable by the new installer?

Comment: omg... I forgot to escape the backslash. Really sorry about wasting your time. Thank you for all help and patience!